Apache Nifi : puthdfs Processor (ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.UnmodifiableMap )
I am using Apache NIFI 1.28  version and i have successfully configured the  core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml , correctly. These configuration files are extracted from HDP2.5.0 Hortonworks Ambari but when i run the processor it is giving the following error:

13:00:11 PKT ERROR PutHDFS[id=d2b7ad77-0192-1000-e937-9d1797c4e0fd]
Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run,
NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the
'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap - Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.commons.collections.map.UnmodifiableMap I have included all
possible combination of different jar files but all in vain, i am also
attaching the lib folder as well



